# Spring Boot Could not resolve placeholder while reading second database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to read second database connection information from application properties in my module. My configuration module should read values.

## Configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.second-datasource")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

When I call DatabaseConfiguration inside of the controller, it gives an error.

```
private DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration;
databaseConfiguration.getUrl();
.
.
.
```

## Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'url' in value "${url}"
```

I found some solutions such as this one

[Spring boot could not resolve placeholder in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158249/spring-boot-could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string)

I implemented it.

## POM.XML

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>//artifactID</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>fraud-core</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
   //Parent
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <HMN_CDM_Facade.version>TEST-SNAPSHOT</HMN_CDM_Facade.version>
    <hmn.dependency.scope>compile</hmn.dependency.scope>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    //DEPENDENCIES
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your application.properties file

Comment: Remove the `@Value` annotations as well as the `@PropertySource`.

Comment: instead of ${url} use ${spring.datasource.url}

Comment: Take a look to this answer. Although it is about Spring Batch, it shows how to use a secondary datasource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982583/3046834

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two ways of reading configurations data in spring-boot.

@Value should be used when you have an individual property that has to be accessed inside a @Component.. basically it is a one of thing like

```
 Ex: max.threads=10
 Which can be accessed in a component using @Value.
```

The Configuration properties way is when you have multiple values and are functionally grouped.

```
Ex: server.names:
     -
      server1
     -
      server2
```

Now for this you should use configuration properties.

Do not mix both. You should not use @Value inside a configuration properties java file.

Answer (score 0):

@Value("${url}") ,this way of writing corresponds to the 'application.propertice' or 'application.yml' file. The correct way of writing below.

[image]

Comment: I believe that there is no 'correct way' of property naming. In this case correct property name in `.yml` or `.properties` is exactly `spring.second-datasource.url` ...