# Injection of autowired dependencies failed for environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, application.properties

I tried multiple solution on SO and none worked on centos 7

i have:

```
$ echo $DBSERVER
mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017
```

application.properties

```
db.server=${DBSERVER}
```

my config

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Value("${db.server}")
    private String server;
    ...

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(
                new MongoClientURI(server)
        );
    }
}
```

i tried:

[Spring Could not Resolve placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307237/spring-could-not-resolve-placeholder/28307348)

[Could not resolve placeholder in string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244696/could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string-value)

[Could not resolve Spring property placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder/34576363)

[Spring Could not Resolve placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307237/spring-could-not-resolve-placeholder/28307348)

[Spring boot could not resolve placeholder in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158249/spring-boot-could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string)

also i tried to add filtering but its not working

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

but i still get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoConfiguration':
  Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Could not resolve placeholder 'DBSERVER' in value "${DBSERVER}"
```