# property value not resolved from application.properties using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I use this configure

application.properties

```sh
user.name.auth=s-SGH-S0007
```

```java
 @Value("${user.name.auth}")
    private String userNameAuth;
```

when I try to get a value from a given property, then I get an error.

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.name.auth' in value "${user.name.auth}"

how can I get around this error (without using yaml)?

Comment: This indicates that the value isn't loaded from `application.properties`. This has nothing to do with "special" characters in the value.

Comment: You're right. I have seen.

Comment: there isn't enough information in this question to give an answer, but as a guess: are you using maven but not inheriting from spring boot starter parent?

Comment: Other possible causes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158249/spring-boot-could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I was running an integration test, and the values for the properties were only specified in the application. properties of the application, so I got an error. If the entry point is in the test loop, then there it was necessary to define the desired properties in application.properties as well.